# Geth network stopped mining

Tags: mining, poa, geth-clique

On my POA network there are 5 nodes/miners but suddenly all nodes stopped mining and giving this in console
`"INFO [09-05|08:50:16.267] Looking for peers peercount=4 tried=4 static=0".`

We tried to check the pending transactions in the txpool which showed this message on 3 of the miners and 2 miners listed 0 pending transactions

txpool.status

{
pending: 3,
queued: 0
}

If we try to start the mining by using miner.start() then the console shows the message as

`INFO [09-05|08:53:23.471] Commit new mining work                   number=7961999 sealhash="d93ccf…cdb147" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="94.336µs"`
`INFO [09-05|08:53:23.471] Signed recently, must wait for others`
`INFO [09-05|08:57:23.483] Commit new mining work                   number=7961999 sealhash="c3f025…388121" uncles=0 txs=1 gas=21000 fees=0.0050589 elapsed="562.983µs"`
`INFO [09-05|08:57:23.484] Signed recently, must wait for others`

I have also  tried to remove the miner from list by using `clique.propose('*miner address*',false)` but it does not remove the miner from the network.

Can anyone suggest what should I do that all nodes start mining again? I've tried "miner.start()" but it did not help.

Comment: What is the most recent block in each of the nodes? From your description it seems the network is partitioned and neither partition have enough member to continue mining new blocks.

Comment: 2 nodes were on 7998687, 2 were on 7998688 and 1 node was on 7998689 block. 
The nodes were looking for other miners on the network and gave the message `Looking for peers` but I think they could not communicate over the network and went into a deadlock situation to mine the new block. 
I was able to fetch the previous transactions over the network but could not post new ones.

Comment: You have three forks but none of them have 3 signers. For 5 signer a majority of 3 is required. You have to choose one of the forks as main chain and reset the other signers so they connect to main chain.

Comment: All the nodes showed 5 signers when I used the `clique.getSigners()` command. How can we choose one of the forks in that case ??